# Accessing Spring Security Role Hierarchy Programatically

Tags: spring, spring-security, javabeans

I have a Spring Security role hierarchy set up like this:

```
ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_MANAGER
ROLE_MANAGER > ROLE_USER
ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
```

I found myself needing to create a VetoableChangeListener that can veto PropertyChangeEvents based on the role (due to one of those silly Legacy Design issue).

So, in my vetoableChange() method, a change will need to be vetoed based on the hierarchy. For example, a certain field cannot be changed by any role below ROLE_MANAGER in the defined hierarchy, so if a ROLE_USER tries to change it, a PropertyVetoException is thrown.

```
public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) throws PropertyVetoException {

    String role = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getRoles().get(0);
    String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
    String requiredRole = getRequiredRole(propertyName);

    // determine if the current role is equal to or greater than
    // the required role, throw PropertyVetoException if not

}
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 5):

In your listener use directly `RoleHierarchy` that you defined.

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole));
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> reachableRoles = roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities(roles);

if (reachableRoles.contains(requiredRole)) {
    // allow
} else {
    // deny
}
```

Method `getReachableGrantedAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>)` returns an array of all reachable authorities. Reachable authorities are the directly assigned authorities plus all authorities that are (transitively) reachable from them in the role hierarchy.

**Example:**

Role hierarchy: ROLE_A > ROLE_B and ROLE_B > ROLE_C.

Directly assigned authority: ROLE_A.

Reachable authorities: ROLE_A, ROLE_B, ROLE_C.